# I get the warning "Field 'Enemy.AI.animator' is never assigned"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a code to move an enemy between 2 points, when he reaches the minimum he will stop.
I get the error because it says that the animator has no assigned variable, but I set it in the start method. It also says that and the animator will always have its default value null, I don't know what to do.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    //assigning variables
    public float moveSpeed;
    public Transform target;
    public float chaseRadius;
    public float attackRadius;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Animator animator;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //getting the necessary components
        animator.GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        CheckDistance();
    }
    //checking distance between 2 points and setting the rigid body to move
    void CheckDistance() 
    {
        if(Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position) <= chaseRadius && Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position) > attackRadius)
        {


             Vector3 temp = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
             ChangeAnim(temp - transform.position);
             rb.MovePosition(temp);
        }
    }
   //changing animations of the object
    private void ChangeAnim(Vector2 direction)
    {
        if (Mathf.Abs(direction.x) > Mathf.Abs(direction.y))
        {
            Debug.Log("x is greater");
            if(direction.x > 0) 
            {
                animator.SetFloat("moveX", direction.x);
            }
            else if(direction.x < 0) 
            {
                animator.SetFloat("moveX", direction.x);
            }
        }else if (Mathf.Abs(direction.x) < Mathf.Abs(direction.y))
        {
            Debug.Log("y is greater");
            if (direction.y > 0)
            {
                animator.SetFloat("moveX", direction.y);
            }
            else if (direction.y < 0)
            {
                animator.SetFloat("moveX", direction.y);
            }
        }
    }
}

Player Script:

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    private Vector3 change;
    private Animator animator;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    { 
        change = Vector3.zero;
        change.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        change.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        UpdateAnimationAndMove();
    }

    void UpdateAnimationAndMove() 
    {
        if (change != Vector3.zero)
        {
            MoveCharacter();
            animator.SetFloat("moveX", change.x);
            animator.SetFloat("moveY", change.y);
            animator.SetBool("moving", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("moving", false);
        }

    }

    void MoveCharacter() 
    {
        myRigidbody.MovePosition
            (
            transform.position + change * speed * Time.deltaTime
        );

    }

}
```

Comment: *but I set it in the start method* **where ?**

Comment: animator.GetComponent<Animator>();

Comment: *animator.GetComponent<Animator>()* where? setting need set operator(=) i dont's see it here

Comment: You probably want to create a constructor in your EnemyAI, to which you can pass the animator you want and assign it to the animator in the EnemyAI

Comment: i have just started a few weeks ago scripting in unity, so If you could show me how to do that, i would appreciate it

Comment: yes, sorry for not knowing how to code

Comment: Note that C# != UnityScript. UnityScript is a Javascript derivative created for Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a constructor to your EnemyAI class which can be passed an animator object.

```
public EnemyAI(Animator animator) 
{
  this.animator = animator;
}
```

If you look at your start function in PlayerMovement you see this:

```
void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

and your EnemyAI has this:

```
void Start()
{
    //getting the necessary components
    animator.GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

You can see the last one does not assign the animator.
Change your EnemyAI start function to this:

```
void Start()
{
    //getting the necessary components
    this.animator = animator.GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

Comment: sorry but I still don't know how to do it, I've done the exact same thing in my player script and there It's working

Comment: edit your question to show your player script. Also post the code where you call EnemyAI

Comment: I am calling for the EnemyAI script whenever the player enters the chaseRadius

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help